# Handle redirection from an api : going back properly

Tags: reactjs, nestjs

On my NestJS server, I am implementing an authenticate method using an API. Here is my user's route:

```
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private userService: UserService) {}

    @Get('signup42')
    @UseGuards(FortyTwoAuthGuard)
    async Auth() { }

    @Get('sign42')
    @UseGuards(FortyTwoAuthGuard)
    async Callback(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
        return ( await this.authService.forty2signup(req, res));
    }
```

I am using a strategy where user is making a request to the api, and is redirected to my sign42 function if the api validate the profil of the user:

```
export class Auth42Strategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, '42')
{
    constructor (private config: ConfigService, private authService: AuthService) {
        super({
            clientID: config.get('UID_42_API'),
            clientSecret: config.get('SECRET_42_API'),
            callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3001/auth/sign42',
            // callbackURL: config.get('CALL_BACK_URL_42_API'),
            // profileFields: ['id', 'login', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'email', 'image_url'],
            scope: 'public',
        })
    }

    async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any, done: VerifyCallback): Promise<any> {
        return done(null, profile);
    }
}
```

**My issue there is that when the user decide to go back clicking on the back button in the browser, he is not redirected to the autentication page of my website but to the website handling the api** (ecole 42 ;) ). **I tried to implement a navigate(-2) strategy in my front end but doesn t work.**

Any help ??